# \ifnum conflict with appendix

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, numbering, appendices, fancyhdr

Was helped briliantly before, here's another small problem I do not get fixed:

Using the fancyhdr package I get, as promised, fancy headers. However, a chapter in the frontmatter gets a 0. Chaptername and the Table of Contents simply Table of Contents.

So, the aim is to get rid of everything with a zero in my make-up.

I redefine the chaptermark command as follows:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{ \ifnum\thechapter>0 \thechapter.\space\fi #1}{}}}
```

But having Appendices, numbered A, B, C etc. this gives an error as follows:

> `Missing number, treated as zero.`

Well, to be expected. How to solve this decently?

Comment: *Why* does a chapter in the frontmatter get a 0? Please provide a minimal working example.

Comment: Frontmatter in a document is typically associated with an Abstract, ToC, LoF, LoT, Preface, etc. These are set as `\chapter*` or numberless chapters. So, printing of `0. ChapterName` in the header is expected since no `chapter` counter has been incremented. That's also why they don't show up in the ToC, since `\chapter*` doesn't by default (you need to do this manually via `\addcontentsline`). Finally, Appendices have `\thechapter` set as `\Alph{chapter}`. You should instead test for `\value{chapter}>0`, rather than `\thechapter>0`.

Comment: Dang -- `fancyhdr` produces "CHAPTER 0", contrary to the bare `book` class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should think to `\thechapter` as the representation of the chapter number in some strange radix: a numeric test like `100>20` would give wrong results if the left hand side is in base two and the right hand side in base 10 and you're doing something similar. So what you want to test is the "abstract" value of the counter:

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\space\fi #1}{}}}
```

Comment: That will do, I really learn something about all those engine commands of LaTeX

A new world to me, should read more about it I think!

Comment: `\ifnum\value` seems to not really be reliable (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434339/18401).