# titleps' headers lose their numbers just before \appendix

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, titleps

In the following MWE, the headers are customized, thanks to the `titleps` package. They are supposed to display the chapter and the section (depending on the parity of the page):

1. the corresponding numbers (and, for the chapter, the chapter name), *but only if they are numbered*,
2. title.

For the former condition, I defined new commands `\chapterheader` and `\sectionheader` involving some tests. The whole machinery works well, except for the two last pages (pages 11 and 12) before the appendix: the numbers disappear from the headers.

It is easy to fix the problem with `\cleardoublepage` inserted just before `\appendix` but do you see why this problem by default?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titleps}
%
\newcommand*{\chapterheader}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumcomp{\value{secnumdepth}}{>}{-1}} and test {\ifnumcomp{\value{chapter}}{>}{0}}
  }{%
    \MakeUppercase\chaptername{}\ \thechapter.
  }{%
  }%
  \chaptertitle%
}%
\newcommand*{\sectionheader}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumcomp{\value{secnumdepth}}{>}{0}} and test {\ifnumcomp{\value{chapter}}{>}{0}}
  }{%
    \thesection.
  }{%
  }%
  \sectiontitle%
}%
%
\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}[]{%
  \sethead[\thepage]%
  []%
  [\chapterheader]%
  {%
    \ifcsempty{\sectiontitle}{%
      \chapterheader%
    }{%
      \sectionheader%
    }%
  }%
  {}%
  {\thepage}%
  \headrule%
}%
%
\newcommand{\dummytext}{%
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \lipsum[1-5]

  \section{A section}
  \lipsum[1-15]
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
%
\dummytext
\dummytext
%
% \cleardoublepage
%
\appendix
\dummytext
\dummytext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \appendix sets the chapter counter to 0. Without the \cleardoublepage the command is executed on the page where the section ends.

Comment: Indeed, but why is it executed so early (two pages before)?

Comment: That's where the appendix command is. Add `\pretocmd\appendix{some text}{}{\fail}` to your document and check where "some text" is.

Comment: Right. Does it mean `\appendix`'s definition would be better if it would contain a `\cleardoublepage` or `\clearpage` (depending on `openright` or not)?

Comment: Imho you should better correct the header definitions. They shouldn't rely on \value{chapter}. titleps takes care that \thesection and \thechapter is correct in the header but doesn't touch the counters.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't see how headers can not rely on counters if I want some text (e.g. `\chaptername` or the chapter/section numbers, followed by a period) to be displayed only if the corresponding chapter/section is numbered (which is not the case for instance in `\frontmatter` with the `book` class).

Comment: Your own code is an example why you can't rely on them. headers are made later and the state of counters can have changed then. Another example: put two or more \section on a page and add to the header `\the\value{section}` and compare the output with `\thesection`. So your tests should go inside the mark command. E.g. scrbook has something like `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\ifnumbered{chapter}{number}{} title}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`titleps` provides a macro for cases like this, which «Adds a command or a variable to the list of “marks” to be emitted at a sectioning command». Just add the following line:

```
\newtitlemark*{chapter}
```

Now `\value{chapter}` will return the correct value. This is not done by default because typically only `\thechapter` is used.

Comment: I must admit `\newtitlemark` looks still mysterious to my eyes :) But, anyway, that works well! The only remaining problem is `\chaptername` instead of `\appendixname` in the appendix, but I will investigate a bit and ask a new question if necessary.

Comment: You say "This is not done by default because typically only `\thechapter` is used" but how could I rely on `\thechapter` to test whether a chapter is numbered (value > 0) or not in case of, e.g., appendix chapters where `\thechapter` typically are case alphabetic characters?